# How to iterate over an xml and save it into a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, dataframe, elementtree

I have an `XML` and i'm trying to iterate over it and save it(just the `tracking events` part) into a `dataframe`.

this is the `input` XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trackingresponse>
   <trackingdetails>
      <trackingdetail>
         <trackingnumber>1550161004</trackingnumber>
         <trackingevents>
            <trackingevent>
               <date>2020-10-21T11:04:00+01:00</date>
               <code>17</code>
            </trackingevent>
            <trackingevent>
               <date>2020-10-21T08:41:00+01:00</date>
               <code>18</code>
            </trackingevent>
    </trackingdetail>
   </trackingdetails>
</trackingresponse>
```

i tried this code but it shows empty dataframe :

```
    response =requests.post(endpoint_url, data=t, headers = headers).text
    # response is correct
    response_tree = ET.fromstring(response)
    data = []
    for el in response_tree.iter('./*'):
        for i in el.iter('*'):
            data.append(dict(i.items()))

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
```

also i tried writing `text` values into a temp dataframe, but this wont either :

```
response_df = pd.read_csv('/home/test.csv')
response_df['date']= response_tree.find('.//date').text
response_df['code']= response_tree.find('.//code').text
```

i also tried this , but its giving me everything element as a new row :

```
for child in tree.iter('trackingevent'): 
  for elem in child.iter():
       data = {str(elem.tag):[elem.text]}
       if str(elem.text)=='None':continue
       response_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
       consolidated_list.append(response_df)
```

i'm just trying to get the `tracking events` inside the `xml` into a `dataframe`

expected dataframe:

```
date                              code
2020-10-21T11:04:00+01:00         17
2020-10-21T08:41:00+01:00         18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code does the job

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trackingresponse>
   <trackingdetails>
      <trackingdetail>
         <trackingnumber>1550161004</trackingnumber>
         <trackingevents>
            <trackingevent>
               <date>2020-10-21T11:04:00+01:00</date>
               <code>17</code>
            </trackingevent>
            <trackingevent>
               <date>2020-10-21T08:41:00+01:00</date>
               <code>18</code>
            </trackingevent>
          </trackingevents>
      </trackingdetail>
   </trackingdetails>
</trackingresponse>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [{'date': e.find('date').text, 'code': e.find('code').text} for e in root.findall('.//trackingevent')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
                        date code
0  2020-10-21T11:04:00+01:00   17
1  2020-10-21T08:41:00+01:00   18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to parse the XML with `etree` (note: you're missing `</trackingevents>` in your XML snippet, probably a typo):

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.ElementTree(file='<your file.xml>')

data = []
for ev in tree.findall('.//trackingevent'):
    date = ev.find('date').text
    code = ev.find('code').text
    data.append({
        'date': date,
        'code': code
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        date code
0  2020-10-21T11:04:00+01:00   17
1  2020-10-21T08:41:00+01:00   18
```

Comment: `for ev in response.findall('.//trackingevent'):  'str' object has no attribute 'findall'`